# BATCH: How to read a .txt file to delete certain listed files with a certain filename

Tags: batch-file, command-line, windows-7, cmd, command-prompt

Hoping i can have some help with a batch file i am making.

My batch file currently scans a directory and notes all the folders, subfolders and exports them in a list.txt file, by doing the following:

```
dir /a "special\program\"/s /b /-p /o:gen >list.txt
```

And it works fine. However what i now want to do is scan the list.txt file and delete certain filenames from the path in the .txt file, i don't want to delete filetypes but instead delete a part of the name.

Because basically theirs over 50 files in each folder and some of the files may contain the name example:
[image]

Look at the files: file_kool.rar, fileOk.rar, somethingRANDOM.rar, i would like to delete the files with out the name "file" in them so "somethingRANDOM.rar, excluding file_kool.rar and fileOk.rar, but i am not sure how to add the exclusions because i cannot specify every filename to delete as their is way too many so i am guessing theirs a way i can use a Wildcard to exclude .rar files with "file" in them and only delete the unnoted .rar files?

I tried this:

```
@echo off
::Check Directories, Sub-Folders and list all files within and save to a list.txt file
dir /a "special\program\"/s /b /-p /o:gen >list.txt
::Read list.txt and delete all .rar files accept for the exception ones with "file" in them
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (list.txt) do del /s special\program\ *file?
```

Or instead of this is their a way in robocopy to exclude file:
IDEA#2:

```
robocopy "program" "special\program" /e /xf *something.rar* *.rar /xd random random2 *file?
```

I tried this one which is the preferred choice i am after but i couldn't workout how in the exclusions to add the fact that i want to delete all .rar files accept for ones that contain "file"(exclusions).

Does anyone have a workaround. I am sure their is something simple here i am missing?

NOTE: I have fixed my question sorry everyone, as i typed it out i confused myself.

Comment: please rephrase your problem. At start, you state you want to delete file*.rar, and then that you do not want to copy them from your original source. This is not the same question. And from you r below comment, please be clearer on the patterns you have to handle. It seems more complex than you initial post.

Comment: Cheers for the advice Mat, i did not realise how confusing my question was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Batch file below deletes all files with names that start with "file" placed inside "special\program" folder:

```
cd "special\program"
del /S file*.*
```

If you want to delete files with names that contain "file" at any place, just change the wild-card by: `*file*.*`

**EDIT**: *Reply to the comment*

In your question you said: "i would like to delete the files with the name "file" in them", so I thought you want to delete the files that have "file" in any part of the filename. Now you said *in a comment* that you want the reverse thing! I strongly encourage you to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23189712/batch-how-to-read-a-txt-file-to-delete-certain-listed-files-with-a-certain-fil/23190656#comment35551906_23190656) and make this point clear including the fact that you changed the original question; otherwise the people that may read this topic will be confused until they read your small comment at the very end of the topic... `:-(`

Anyway, the Batch file below do what you want (I hope so), that is: delete all .rar files in "special\program" folder *excepting* those that have "file" substring in *any part* of the file name.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /R "special\program" %%a in (*.rar) do (
   set "filename=%%~Na"
   if "!filename:file=!" equ "%%~Na" del "%%a"
)
```

Comment: Note that `file` can appear in the short filename by random chance and the short filename is also parsed, leading to unwanted deletions.

Comment: Cheers Aacini, sorry about the confusion, hopefully my question makes sense now, after a few days offline, re-reading my old question good point mate, i was just frustrated at the time and couldn't post what i meant.

Comment: So? Did my second solution solved your problem or not?

Answer (score 0):

```
dir /a "special\program\"/s /b /-p /o:gen |find /v /i "file" >list.txt
```

should do what you appear to be asking.

Examples of data as you have it and as you want it go a long way....

Comment: You need to explain what you are trying to achive by editing some representative data into your question. It's simply not clear whether you want to exclude the lines containing the string "file" from the report, or replace the string "file" in the report with something else (like `nothing`) or rename the files or delete the files or whether you have some other list of target names which you want to use to perform that exclusion/deleteion/renaming - not just the name "file". Otherwise, this just becomes a guessing game...

Comment: The question changed, Magoo.